# Change "require('events').eventEmitter" to"require('events')"?

Tags: node.js

My teacher told me to use:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').eventEmitter;
```

But, the current nodejs documentation says to use:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
```

Is my teacher wrong, did node.js change or why is this?

Comment: It appears you can use either in the most recent versions of node, but you used to need to use `require('events').eventEmitter`.

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer and hopefully give you an example of what a question should be like.  If this is not exactly what you intended, then please correct it, but make an effort to keep it very clear.

Answer (score 5):

Nodejs used to require you to use:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').eventEmitter
```

But, in May 2013, [this change](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/6ed861dd7feea33224d1cac8e64010b45974ae51) was submitted on GitHub:

> events: have events module exports EventEmitter This change is 100%
>   backwards compatible.
>
> This change will make using `EventEmitter` slightly simpler / nicer
>   and adheres to the best practice set forth by substack.
>
> ```
> var EventEmitter = require("events")
>
> var emitter = new EventEmitter()
> ```
>
> The only difference is that we now have to set `EventEmitter` as a
>   property of `EventEmitter` for backwards compatibility like we do with
>   [`Stream`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/6ed861dd7feea33224d1cac8e64010b45974ae51)
>
> We have also set the `usingDomains` property on the `EventEmitter`
>   constructor itself because that aligns with it's current usage of
>   `require("events").usingDomains = true`
>
> There are other internals that would benefit from this change as well
>   like `StringDecoder`

Which now allows the simpler syntax:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events');
```

while still maintaining backwards compatibility with the older syntax.

Comment: Why the downvote?  The OP is asking about `const eventEmitter=require ('events');` vs. `const  eventEmitter = require('events').eventEmitter` and this shows the actual GitHub checkin where the capability to do `const eventEmitter=require ('events');` was added and shows the comment explaining it and how that change was made backward compatible.

Comment: some people are just sitting to downvote here without any reason